# Doctrine: String keys with Array hydration

Tags: php, doctrine

According to their [documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/working-with-models/en#fetching-objects), you should use Array hydration rather than record hydration when retrieving data for read-only purposes.

However, this means I have to access the attributes of the retrieved object using arrays and string keys:

```
$user['Phonenumbers'][0]['number']
```

instead of the OO style:

```
$user->PhoneNumbers[0]->number
```

Now I'm kinda new to PHP, but in other languages I've worked with the 2nd notation would be preferable because typos would be caught at compile time while typos in string literals would not be noticed until runtime.  Does this apply to PHP/Doctrine?

Answer (score 0):

Typos in both notations will **NOT** be caught at compile time. Typos in both notations will produce only `PHP_NOTICE` and application will continue running unless you try to do some illegal operation (e.g. calling undefined method).

Consider misstyping 'Phonenumbers' to 'Phonenombers':

```
$number = $user['Phonenombers'][0]['number'];  // Notice: Undefined index
$number = $user->PhoneNombers[0]->number;      // Notice: Undefined property
```

Or in case of misstyping 'user' to 'userr':

```
$number = $userr->PhoneNombers[0]->number; 
  // Notice: Undefined variable
  // Notice: Trying to get property of non-object
```

In all cases above the variable `$number` will be set to `NULL`.

On the other hand following code will cause `PHP_ERROR` and script will stop executing

```
$userr->free(); //Fatal error: Call to undefined method
```

All examples above will produce `PHP_NOTICE` or `PHP_ERROR` respectively only when executed while script is running. For example the following will **NOT** produce any `PHP_NOTICE` or `PHP_ERROR`:

```
if(false) {
   $userr->free();
}
```

So, finally, the answer is NO, this does not apply to PHP/Doctrine. If you don't need any methods of `Doctrine_Collection` object, you should use array hydration instead, because it's faster and uses less memory.